# Why does not the ContextMenu(popup menu) show up?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, contextmenu, popupmenu

The following class derives from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`. In said class I call `OpenFileDialog` to open a XAML file (workflow file). Next, I implement a dynamic menu when right clicking the mouse.   The menu does not show up.  Is this a threading problem or a UI problem? In my research I've been unable to discover a solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
private void File_Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    fileDialog.Title  = "Open Workflow";
    fileDialog.Filter = "Workflow| *.xaml";

    if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        LoadWorkflow(fileDialog.FileName);
        MouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(mouseClickedResponse);
     }
}

private void mouseClickedResponse(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
         LoadMenuItems();
    }
}

private void LoadMenuItems()
{
    System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu contextmenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();   
    System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem item1 = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();
    item1.Header = "A new Test";
    contextmenu.Items.Add(item1);
    this.ContextMenu = contextmenu;
    this.ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: You have to add the ContextMenu before you click. The ContextMenu uses whatever you bind it to as a PlacementTarget. ContextMenus are triggered on the click, not after the click, which is why nothing shows up. You could always just set the context menu, then set the UserControl.ContextMenu IsEnabled value to false until you want it to be clickable.

Comment: Bob is right, the context menu has to be bound to some parent control (common behaviour using wpf/xaml), you are not on win forms i guess, using wpf will lead you to have the context menu defined before!

Comment: thanks for your reply.I tried your solutions  and it did not work.

Comment: do you tried exactly this: defining a ContextMenu using xaml in your WPF Ui code file (not code behind file *.cs): http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.aspx on the bottom is some sample code shown - which directly applies to the thesis of Bob and me. If your current try does not worked out too - can you please provide your xaml code?

Comment: You are helping me and thank you for that.  I moved the contextmenu setting to before clicking and now I do see the context menu.  However the context menu only appears in 2 of the three panes of the UI.  I am creating a WorkflowDesigner and that opens a screen (window) woth three panes. The activityBuilder Pane is the one that the context menu does not appear on.  Also, I don't have anythin in my Xaml about context menu and just by ading the contextMenu to before clicking, I can see it. So, thought I mention this .  Thanks again

Comment: No problem at all, it's great that we could help you. But I used xaml code for builing my context menus and got no problems with that. But if it's working for you the way you implemented it, it's fine :)

Answer (score 7):

Came across this problem myself, I used this:

```
ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

[MSDN Documentation on ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the ContextMenu's [Show(Control, Point)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s00cc2f3.aspx)  method.
furthermore i wouldn't instantiate a new context menu each time the control is clicked, instead i would do something like that:

```
MyClass()
{
     // create the context menu in the constructor:

     this.ContextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();   
     System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem item1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
     item1.Text = "A new Test";
     this.ContextMenu.Items.Add(item1);
}


private void mouseClickedResponse(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
          // show the context menu as soon as the right mouse button is pressed
          this.ContextMenu.Show(this, e.Location);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But in my case this.ContextMenu  does not have a Show method.  I get red line under the "Show" and it does not compile. I am however using system.Windows.Controls in my code. Could it be I need to be using a different assembly or a diffferent version?

Comment: I also tried your solution it dd not work probably one reason would be that I can't use this line of your code :this.ContextMenu.Show(this, e.Location); 
I am open for suggestions, thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I just recognized that you are using Windows Presentation Foundation, not Windows Forms. The WPF ContextMenu doesn't have a Show method. I'm not familiar with WPF, but this [http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html](http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html) could help you. And this [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu) is the correct documentation page for your class.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to call `contextMenu.Show`

Comment: The problem is that my contextMenu does not have a Show method?  I don't know why.